# CPLEX + YALMIP -- "Solver not found"?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I'm trying to get started with [YALMIP](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Tutorials.Installation), which is a Matlab interface to optimization solvers such as [CPLEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex-optimizer/). I have an objective function `obj` and constraints `cons`, and I've plugged them into Yalmip...

```
options=sdpsettings('solver','Cplex'); %windows needs uppercase 'Cplex' and unix is ok with 'cplex' or 'Cplex'
solvesdp(cons,obj,options); %prints 'Warning: Solver not found'
```

In the above code, `solvesdp` prints **Warning: Solver not found**. The `.m` containing `obj`, `cons`, and the calls to Yalmip works on my friend's computer, and we're stumped about why it's not working on my computer.

---

Here are the setup steps for CPLEX and Yalmip that I did on my **Ubuntu 12.04** machine with **Matlab R2012b**:

1. Installed IBM CPLEX here: `/home/user/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex`
2. Installed Yalmip here: `home/user/yalmip`
3. Added CPLEX and Yalmip to my Matlab path (and confirmed that all directories exist):

```
    addpath(genpath('/home/user/yalmip'))
    addpath(genpath('/home/user/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/matlab'))
    addpath(genpath('/home/user/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/examples/src/matlab'))
```

---

**Below, I explain how I've tried to *diagnose* the problem. It's apparent that Matlab can see CPLEX, Matlab can see Yalmip, but Yalmip can't see CPLEX.**

Confirmed that Yalmip and CPLEX are in my matlab path:

```
MATLAB> path
    /home/user/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/examples/src/matlab
    /home/user/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/matlab
    /home/forrest/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/matlab/help
    /home/forrest/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/matlab/help/helpsearch
    /home/forrest/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/matlab/help/topics
    /home/user/yalmip
    /home/user/yalmip/demos
    /home/user/yalmip/extras
    /home/user/yalmip/modules
    /home/user/yalmip/modules/bilevel
    /home/user/yalmip/modules/global
    /home/user/yalmip/modules/moment
    /home/user/yalmip/modules/parametric
    /home/user/yalmip/modules/robust
    /home/user/yalmip/modules/sos
    /home/user/yalmip/operators
    /home/user/yalmip/solvers
    ...
```

To verify that Matlab can indeed find CPLEX, I ran `help cplexlp`. It gave valid output:

```
MATLAB> help cplexlp
cplexlp
Solve linear programming problems.
x = cplexlp(f,Aineq,bineq) solves the linear programming problem min f*x such that Aineq*x <= bineq.
...
```

Also, `which cplex` gives this output: `/home/user/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/matlab/@Cplex/Cplex.p`

And `which yalmip` gives this output: `/home/user/yalmip/extras/yalmip.m`

I ran `yalmiptest` on the Matlab command prompt. The output verifies that Matlab can find Yalmip, but Yalmip can't find CPLEX:

```
MATLAB> yalmiptest
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|       Searching for installed solvers       |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|        Solver|   Version/module|      Status|
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|       LINPROG|                 |       found|
|      QUADPROG|                 |       found|
|        LMILAB|                 |       found|
|       FMINCON|        geometric|       found|
|       FMINCON|         standard|       found|
|    FMINSEARCH|                 |       found|
|           BNB|                 |       found|
|      BINTPROG|                 |       found|
|        CUTSDP|                 |       found|
|        BMIBNB|                 |       found|
|         KKTQP|                 |       found|
|          NONE|                 |       found|
|     LSQNONNEG|                 |       found|
|        LSQLIN|                 |       found|
|        GUROBI|           GUROBI|   not found|
|        GUROBI|              MEX|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|         CPLEXINT|   not found|
|           CBC|                 |   not found|
|          GLPK|       GLPKMEX-CC|   not found|
```

---

I also looked around the IBM forums for answers to this. A friend pointed me to [this post in the IBM forums](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14611925) about diagnosing CPLEX/Yalmip, but the post is more Windows-focused and it didn't really solve my problem.

---

More details:

- Yalmip version 2012-09-26
- CPLEX version 12.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging into the Yalmip source code, I eventually found the problem.

In the Yalmip source code, there's a file called `yalmip/solvers/definesolvers.m`. In `definesolvers.m`, there are a bunch of statements like this:

```
solver(i) = lpsolver;
solver(i).tag     = 'CPLEX';
solver(i).version = 'IBM';
solver(i).subversion = '12.4';
solver(i).checkfor = {'cplexlp.m','cplexlink124'};
...
```

These statements exist for CPLEX 12.0, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, and 12.4. But, I'm using CPLEX 12.5, and there's no statement like this for CPLEX 12.5.

I replaced all instances of `12.4` with `12.5` and replaced instances of `cplexlink124` with `cplexlink125`. My optimization code works now!

Here's the new output of `yalmiptest`:

```
>> yalmiptest
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|       Searching for installed solvers       |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|        Solver|   Version/module|      Status|
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|         CPLEX|              IBM|       found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|       found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|       found|
|       LINPROG|                 |       found|
|      QUADPROG|                 |       found|
|        LMILAB|                 |       found|
|       FMINCON|        geometric|       found|
|       FMINCON|         standard|       found|
|    FMINSEARCH|                 |       found|
|           BNB|                 |       found|
|      BINTPROG|                 |       found|
|        CUTSDP|                 |       found|
|        BMIBNB|                 |       found|
|         KKTQP|                 |       found|
|          NONE|                 |       found|
|     LSQNONNEG|                 |       found|
|        LSQLIN|                 |       found|
|        GUROBI|           GUROBI|   not found|
|        GUROBI|              MEX|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
|         CPLEX|              IBM|   not found|
...
```

I'm guessing that the remaining `CPLEX| IBM| not found|` lines mean that CPLEX 12.0, 12.1, 12.2, and 12.3 aren't found.